# Database Design - 2d tile grid

Tags: mysql, database-design

I played a web game a while back called racewarkingdoms.  It used a 2d text based system.  What interest me is the map.  The map is made up of 255 tiles in X direction, and 255 in Y direction.  There are 5 of these maps total.  But what is amazing is that each one contains so much data.  Each one contains its own 'kingdom' which would be about 50 variables per tile.  Then each one contains 'monsters' with health bars and data that is remembered permanetly.

How would something like this be designed.  I doubt each tile was a table.  I would assume you would have a map1_table with the different elements that would be found in any, but I am just not sure.  I am approaching a situation where I need a similar design, but don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have further questions or want to have more "pictures" / scheme files, or just want to discuss 2D Game Developement, feel free to contact me: stack.YOURNAME.request@accountr.eu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click here for scheme file](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B1F8H42zGlhfMGM2NWYxMjAtODQ1Zi00YzYyLTg3OTEtMzE2MzRiZTI2YTdl&hl=en)

I would recommend to use the following structure combined with my scheme:

- tiles saves the amount of tiles in
  general, each tile has ONE id, the
  size of a tile is hard-coded: 5*5 px
  for example.
- tiles_meta saves the name, and a
  short "tooltip" description. META is
  self-explainary ;)
- tiles_content_low contains a minority
  of the the tile. Here you should
  include the things a user will access
  many times, but keep it minimal.
- tiles_content_medium contains such
  things as "here item xy can be found
  with a chance of 12%". Create an
  addition "loot_table" with items. The
  "item_hash" is a hash of all item ids
  of the items which may drop.
- tiles_content_large is the biggest
  table. Here you store on which
  coordinate inside of the tile the
  player is located, where he looted
  item number 1234 etc.

> ```
> table: tiles
> id
>
> table: tiles_meta
> id
> tile_id
> name
> desc
>
> table: tiles_content_low
> id
> tile_id
> owner_id
> go_id
>
> table: tiles_content_medium
> id
> tile_id
> mob_hash
> item_hash
>
> table: tiles_content_large
> id
> tile_id
> savegame
> ```

If you want to build a tile_set or "map" use JavaScript, do not generate a whole map on your server, just pass the tile date to the JavaScript.
This will save much performance.

Comment: Very good information.  Graphics are not a huge focus as it is pretty much text based, on a non scrolling map.  But still very good... I would have never thought about it from this viewpoint.

Answer (score 4):

First I would start by defining a map like this,

```
MAPS
Id  
Name  
Xmax  
Ymax
```

Here you can define the map by giving it a name and the maximum dimensions. You could use the max dimensions to constraint the tiles.

```
TILES
Id
MapId
X
Y
```

Then construct a tiles properties table to hold all properties associated with a tile.

```
TILEPROPERTIES
Id
TileId
Name
Value
```

This would be my implementation and doesn't mean it should work for you, but it hopefully gets you started.

Comment: Good idea ;), very "small" but it contains the most important structures